# Python for Network Engineers - Router Config Parsing

Tags: python, cisco

I could use some help in parsing a config file where I create lists, where each list has the following format; from the config file (shown below).  I am trying to get my script to read the config file and list interfaces details, for each interface that comes after hostname.

```
PE1-Loopback0-1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
PE2-Loopback0-2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
PE2-GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
PE2-GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

My script looks like this:

```
import random, re, pprint
from collections import defaultdict

routerconfig = open('C:/Users/adrian/workspace/Learning Python/configfile.txt', 'r')

for line1 in iter(routerconfig): #for loop 1.  Pulls out host name
    HostNameRGX = re.search(r'hostname .*', line1)

    if HostNameRGX:
        HostNameGRP = HostNameRGX.group()
        HostName = (HostNameGRP[9:])

        for line2 in iter(routerconfig): #for loop 2.  finds interface details
            IPAddressRGX = re.search(r'[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*.*255\.255.*',line2)
            InterfaceRGX = re.search(r'Loop.*|Giga.*',line2)

            if InterfaceRGX:
                    Interface=InterfaceRGX.group()

            if IPAddressRGX:
                IPAddress = IPAddressRGX.group()
                InterfacePair = (Interface + '-' + IPAddress)
                print(HostName + '-' + InterfacePair) 

routerconfig.close()
```

**OUTPUT FROM MY SCRIPT:**

```
PE1-Loopback0-1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
PE1-Loopback0-2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

I think I know why my output looks like this.  The first for loop (for loop 1) runs a regex for hostname, then continues to the second for loop (for loop 2); which is where I think my problems are.  While the first loop continues to report PE1, the second loop continues to parse the config files under my regex parameters.  I want the second loop to end when it sees another hostname entry, so my script can parse the config for the interface details under PE2, separately from PE1.

The result should look like this:

```
PE1-Loopback0-1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
PE1-GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
PE2-Loopback0-2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
PE2-GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
PE2-GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

**Config File:**

```
   hostname PE1
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel999
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 mpls ip
 mpls label protocol ldp
 tunnel mode mpls traffic-eng
 tunnel destination 2.2.2.2
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng autoroute announce
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-option 10 dynamic
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-selection metric te
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng name PE1-TO-PE2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
 ip rsvp bandwidth
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 205.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
 mpls label protocol ldp
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 mpls traffic-eng administrative-weight 100
 ip rsvp bandwidth 99
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.999
 encapsulation dot1Q 999
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
!


hostname PE2
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel999
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 mpls ip
 mpls label protocol ldp
 tunnel mode mpls traffic-eng
 tunnel destination 2.2.2.2
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng autoroute announce
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-option 10 dynamic
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-selection metric te
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng name PE1-TO-PE2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
 ip rsvp bandwidth
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 205.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
 mpls label protocol ldp
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 mpls traffic-eng administrative-weight 100
 ip rsvp bandwidth 99
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.999
 encapsulation dot1Q 999
 ip address 10.10.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Have any code so far?

Comment: @cricket_007,
I haven't received any code recommendations.  I'm still trying to work on it myself (unsuccessfully).

Comment: It's great that you are editing to show expected outputs, but we aren't going to write the code for you. You'll need to put some attempt into that part, and explain what isn't working for you. For more details, see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your output looks exactly like what you want. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cricket_007,
Look at my OUTPUT, which is the output from my script.  The loop is returning PE1 for all interfaces.  The script should parse the config for interfaces in between host names.

Comment: I see. Can you split the file on the 2 exclamation marks under the hostnames? Then you should get a list of hostname and the section after it.

Comment: Though, I think the problem might be with the second iterator. You read over the all the lines of the file after the first host and don't move the file pointer back

Comment: @cricket_007,
I agree, I think the second loop is the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.  I can't change the config file because this is it's native format; therefore, I want to keep it unaltered.

Comment: I didn't say to change the config file itself. I said use `router_config.strip().split("\n!\n!")`, or some variant of newlines and 2 exclamation marks

Answer (score 1):

**!!!SOLVED!!!**

```
'''
Created on Aug 9, 2016

@author: adrian
'''
import random, re, pprint
from collections import defaultdict
DOT1Q=''
Routers={}
routerconfig = open('configfile.txt', 'r')

for line1 in iter(routerconfig):
    line1 = line1.rstrip('\n')

    if re.match(r'hostname.*', line1):
        HostName = line1[9:]

    else:
        if re.search(r'interface (Loop.*|Giga.*\.[0-9].*)',line1):
            Interface = line1[9:]


        if re.search(r'encap.*dot1[qQ].*',line1):
            DOT1Q = '-' + line1[21:]


        if re.search(r'ip address.*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*.*255\.255.*',line1):
            IPAddress = line1[12:]

            Final=Interface+'-'+IPAddress+DOT1Q
            Routers.setdefault(HostName, []).append(Final)
            print HostName+'-'+Interface+'-'+IPAddress+DOT1Q
            DOT1Q=''
print '\n\n'

routerconfig.close()
pprint.pprint(Routers),
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PE1- Loopback0-1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
PE1- GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.1 255.255.255.0-10
PE1- GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0-999
PE2- Loopback0-2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
PE2- GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.2 255.255.255.0-10
PE2- GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.2 255.255.255.0-999
PE3- Loopback0-3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255
PE3- GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.3 255.255.255.0-10
PE3- GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.3 255.255.255.0-999



{'PE1': [' Loopback0-1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255',
         ' GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.1 255.255.255.0-10',
         ' GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0-999'],
 'PE2': [' Loopback0-2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255',
         ' GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.2 255.255.255.0-10',
         ' GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.2 255.255.255.0-999'],
 'PE3': [' Loopback0-3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255',
         ' GigabitEthernet1.10-205.1.1.3 255.255.255.0-10',
         ' GigabitEthernet1.999-10.10.1.3 255.255.255.0-999']}
```